# How to use arctan2 function inside Keras model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I'm trying to add `arctan2` function to the end of Keras model, but it looks like it is not getting any near even local minimum. Here is my ridiculous but minimal working code with native Keras `Add()` function instead of arctan2 function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal as ss

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv1D, Add
import tensorflow as tf

kernel_size = 64
epochs = 1000

def atan2(tensors):
  Q = tensors[0]
  I = tensors[1]
  return tf.math.atan2(Q, I)

def atan2_output_shape(input_shapes):
    return tuple(input_shapes[0])

atan2_layer = Lambda(atan2, output_shape=atan2_output_shape)

## Data generation for training

x_train = np.random.randn(1024, 512)

t = np.linspace(0, x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[1], endpoint=False)
sine = np.sin(2*np.pi*t/32)
cosine = np.cos(2*np.pi*t/32)

x_I = np.multiply(x_train, cosine)
x_Q = np.multiply(x_train, sine)

b_I = ss.tukey(kernel_size)
b_Q = ss.tukey(kernel_size)

x_I_filt = np.array([np.convolve(b_I, x_I_i, mode='valid') for x_I_i in x_I])
x_Q_filt = np.array([np.convolve(b_Q, x_Q_i, mode='valid') for x_Q_i in x_Q])

y_train = x_Q_filt + x_I_filt
# y_train = x_Q_filt * x_I_filt
# y_train = np.arctan2(x_Q_filt, x_I_filt)

x_I = np.expand_dims(x_I, axis=2)
x_Q = np.expand_dims(x_Q, axis=2)
y_train = np.expand_dims(y_train, axis=2)

## Keras model

input_I = Input(shape=(x_I.shape[1], 1))
input_Q = Input(shape=(x_Q.shape[1], 1))

conv_I_1D = Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=kernel_size, activation=None, padding='valid', use_bias=False)(input_I)
conv_Q_1D = Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=kernel_size, activation=None, padding='valid', use_bias=False)(input_Q)

out_I_Q = Add()([conv_I_1D, conv_Q_1D])
# out_I_Q = Multiply()([conv_I_1D, conv_Q_1D])
# out_I_Q = atan2_layer([conv_Q_1D, conv_I_1D])

model_1D = Model([input_I, input_Q], out_I_Q)

model_1D.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error') 
history_1D = model_1D.fit([x_I, x_Q], y_train, epochs=epochs, verbose=0)
```

and after 100 epochs I'm getting almost perfect initial filter kernel:

```
plt.semilogy(history_1D.history['loss'])
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.show()
```

[image]

It also works well with `Multiply()` function. But if I replace `y_train` to `y_train = np.arctan2(x_Q_filt, x_I_filt)` and `out_I_Q` to `out_I_Q = atan2_layer([conv_Q_1D, conv_I_1D])` I will get this sad loss graph:
[image]

I even initialize weights as they should be but with a little bit of an offset before running`model_1D.fit(...)`. `b_I` and `b_Q` are the same arrays.

```
offset = 1e-5
array_for_I_weights = np.array(model_1D.layers[2].get_weights())
array_for_I_weights[0,:,0,0] = list(b_I+offset)
model_1D.layers[2].set_weights(array_for_I_weights)
model_1D.layers[3].set_weights(array_for_I_weights)
```

Loss graph after training stage will looks like this:
[image]

But if I change `offset` to `1e-4` I will get this loss graph:
[image]
It only getting worse epoch after epoch. What is wrong with arctan2 function in case of placing it inside of Keras model? Why model is jumping away from good minimum? Maybe I should use another custom loss/metric function?

Changing optimizer type won't help at all. I'm using tensorflow 2.0 and Keras 2.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue that you are switching between `tf.math.atan2` and `np.arctan2`. Only use `tf.math.atan2` because that function is designed to work with Keras.